Is the Rocket Lab launch scheduled for May 31 only launching a tiny cubesat?
According to Rocket Lab's website, their Electron can launch 300kg to low Earth orbit. But the PREFIRE cubesat, according to NASA is a 6U cubesat with an 'average weight' for 6U cubesats of .91kg. I couldn't find the exact weight on NASA's site. Is this launch ONLY going to carry the PREFIRE cubesat? Seems a huge waste....

I'm interested in where the 0.91 kg comes from (I think that is probably per U? So 6U would be about 5.5 kg?) If you have any info on that which comes close to being a data point, please feel free to add another answer to Cubesat mass density (kg/U) statistics? Thanks!

According to the PREFIRE mission website, the Thermal IR Spectrometer (TIRS) instrument alone has a mass of "< 3 kg". While, technically, "0.91 kg" is "< 3 kg", that would be a really odd way to describe the mass of the instrument. So, we can assume that the mass of the whole satellite is somewhere > 3 kg.

I guess I misinterpreted the numbers on this web page:https://www.nasa.gov/smallsat-institute/sst-soa/structures-materials-and-mechanisms/#6.2.1. The .91 kg is the weight of the structure only, not the complete satellite.

The Cubesat Design Specification (https://www.cubesat.org/ and click "CDS Rev14") gives a max mass of 2kg per U, so 12kg for 6U. Still not 300, but a good bit more than .91 :)

The whole point of dedicated smallsat launchers like Electron is that they get the payload to exactly the right orbit at exactly the right time. As Rocket Lab states on their website:

Your mission, your way
Tailored orbits, schedule control, responsive launch

Dedicated smallsat launchers like Electron are the taxi of launch systems: they get you exactly where you want to go exactly when you want to go there. Rideshare missions like SpaceX's Transporter and Bandwagon missions are like the bus: the bus station is not your destination, and how you get from the bus station to the final destination is your own problem. Also, the bus leaves and arrives whenever it wants, not when you want.
The two PREFIRE satellites need to be launched within a specific window, otherwise the mission fails. The first PREFIRE satellite launched on May, 25th. That means, the second satellite must be launched within a couple of weeks. Putting a rideshare payload on the mission adds the risk of delays that have nothing to do with Electron or the satellite.
As mentioned in fyrepenguins's answer, the PREFIRE satellites go into a sun-synchronous orbit (SSO).
An SSO guarantees that the satellite will pass over the same reference point on the ground at the same mean local solar time, each time. In other words, it guarantees that there will always be the same lighting conditions and the same shadows on the ground. This is only interesting for a very small portion of satellites: Earth observation satellites using optical imaging and needing to compare a series of images of the same point over time. So, even if you wanted to make this a rideshare mission, you'd still have to find a number of such satellites that also all want to launch at the same time.

according to NASA is a 6U cubesat with an 'average weight' for 6U cubesats of .91kg

Where did you get that number? According to the PREFIRE mission website, the Thermal IR Spectrometer (TIRS) instrument alone has a mass of "< 3 kg". Which would mean the whole satellite is definitely heavier than the instrument alone.
While, technically, "0.91 kg" is "< 3 kg", that would be a really odd way to describe the mass of the instrument.

nit: One specific sun-synchronous orbit (the "dawn/dusk" orbit) is more broadly interesting because satellites in that orbit can have access to solar power without the earth ever blocking the sun.

According to their website, PREFIRE is “<3 kg”, but also launching into a 97.5° “near-polar sun-synchronous orbit”. As this answer shows, as of a few years ago only 16% of satellites were in polar orbits, and I suspect that number has severely dropped since then. That’s ~492/3055 LEO satellites, and as of May 2024 there are just over 6,000 from Starlink alone, all closer to 53° inclination.
That’s all to say, even if this is the only satellite on the mission, that could be because it’s going to an unusual orbit where there aren’t many interested in rideshares.
And as per a Rocket Lab press release:

“It’s these types of missions where Electron really thrives as the leading launch provider for dedicated small satellite missions. We have an excellent track record of delivering NASA’s payloads to exactly where they need to go and when they need to, and we’re looking forward to adding to that tally further with these next back-to-back launches.”

So yes, it’s the only one on the rocket, and it’s only a “waste” in that they didn’t leverage the full payload capacity. But thats where having a cheaper, smaller, dedicate launch is useful; when you have a very particular need. It could potentially cost more to develop a propulsion module to do an inclination change & launch off of a rideshare than to just buy a dedicated launch.

Will be interesting to see if Rocket Lab uses this opportunity to work on 1st stage recovery, since they should have performance margin for a boostback.

@GremlinWranger: The second PREFIRE satellite launches into the same orbit as the one last week, and last week, no recovery attempt was made. Although performance margins are mostly irrelevant, as Electron does not use propulsion for recovery. (Except cold-gas RCS thrusters.)
